# How To Transfer Tokens Out Of Metamask Wallet

Tags: tokens, metamask

I have some tokens in my Metamask wallet and want to transfer them to an exchange to trade but I don't know how to do.  Metamask now allows you to see the tokens as per the recent upgrade but I don't see any way to send tokens.

Would appreciate your advise.

Best regards,

Comment: So basically if you have gotten tokens sent to your Metamask ETH address, you cant send those tokens out of your account yet ? We have to wait for them to program that into the software to do that ? Ive gotten some tokens sent to my Metamask account that i created an ETH wallet on ... Its shwoing the tokens, but i cant send them out :( Once the ICO goes live. Please let me know what I could possibly do.

Answer (score 8):

MetaMask does not have a default UI for sending tokens yet. The official guide lists three current web interfaces that can be used for sending tokens, but none are provided as a default because they do not all necessarily work with all tokens.

Using the [wallet.ethereum.org](https://wallet.ethereum.org) interface, you should be able to manage tokens easily enough.

A default 'send' page will be coming soon.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried importing the private keys into another wallet, say myetherwallet.com (or Mist or Ethereum Wallet from ethereum.org)? 
In case you want to do that, in Metamask open the menu for your wallet (the three dots next to the wallet name) and select 'export private keys', then you can import them in one of said wallets.

Comment: You don't even have to export your keys - myetherwallet has a metamask integration, so you can initiate a metamask transaction using myetherwallet and confirm it using metamask.

Answer (score 2):

You can send tokens using new (as in MetaMask 4.8.0) beta UI.

See official guide [here](https://consensys.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004275431-Sending-Tokens-with-MetaMask-New-UI-).

[image: Beta MetaMask 4.8.0] [image: Beta MetaMask 4.8.0]

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use the ShapeShift MetaMask integration at https://www.efolio.info/shapeshift. It allows you to shift any ERC20 tokens supported by ShapeShift into other crytocurrencies.